# Web application SLA in Gigaspaces cluster

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, gigaspaces

Today I need to deploy my web application(as .war) with embeded space into cluster Service Grid. But when I defined sla properties in pu.xml - only one instance is deployed.

You can see my source code on the next link - [this](https://github.com/VladislavLysov/gigaspaces-cluster-webapp)

Answer (score 0):

The service level agreement features of GigaSpaces should be in sla.xml and not in pu.xml. If you don't provide a sla.xml the container will use the standard deployment (1 instance)

Answer (score 0):

The SLA can also be specified in pu.xml.

Do you have enough available containers?